# Android: How to post live commentary and match updates

Tags: android

I'm sorry but I'm really bad at this. So do bear with me.

A few questions:

1.) How do live score apps provide line-ups, live commentary etc. ?

Do they use RSS feeds and have the mobile app retrieve data from the feed?

2.) Is there any way, where I send updates from my mobile and every one using the app receives these updates?

3.) Is there any documentation that I can read up about live score update apps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detailed functionality really depends on the app and the sports. Usually there is an API involved which can be consumed to retrieve all kinds of data. http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=sports should be a good starting point for sports related API's.

In order to send implement the functionality of sending updates from your device to other user's, you would require some kind of server to help you communicate.

Comment: Very nice link. I appreciate it. Thank you.